# how do i exit an if statement in java?

Tags: java

How do I exit an if statement and continue the loop when the if statement is in the loop? I tried break but it didn't work. Continue just made the program to keep asking me to input a number.

```
import java.io.*;
public class pg48
{
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
        System.out.println("Type a num: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int pro = 1,i,d;
        for (; n != 0; )
        {
            d = n%10;
            if (d == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            pro = pro * d;
            n = n/10;
        }
        System.out.println("Product: "+pro);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `continue;` instead of `break;`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to write the method in this way: `public static void main(String args[])`
If you want to use `continue;`,  you have to  move `n = n / 10;` line before if statement.

Comment: Thx! I used continue and put the line before the if statement and it worked.

Comment: YW, Note that "i" variable is never used.

Answer (score 0):

simple you have to write String[]args in main method. once you write it can be work properly.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. The asker can best tell, but my suspicion is that this is not the problem asked about (you are correct, of course, that `String... commandLineArgs` or similar is missing).